# url of the image which has the largest dimensions of a picture element

Tags: javascript, html

in a picture element, for example this one :

```html
<picture class="l-display-block"> <source srcset="https://cache.marriott.com/marriottassets/marriott/NYCXR/nycxr-bar-8322-hor-feat.jpg?downsize=1440px:*, https://cache.marriott.com/marriottassets/marriott/NYCXR/nycxr-bar-8322-hor-feat.jpg?download=2880px:* 2x" media="(min-width: 1025px)"> <source srcset="https://cache.marriott.com/marriottassets/marriott/NYCXR/nycxr-bar-8322-hor-feat.jpg?downsize=1024px:*, https://cache.marriott.com/marriottassets/marriott/NYCXR/nycxr-bar-8322-hor-feat.jpg?downsize=2048px:* 2x" media="(min-width: 769px)"> <source srcset="https://cache.marriott.com/marriottassets/marriott/NYCXR/nycxr-bar-8322-hor-feat.jpg?downsize=768px:*, https://cache.marriott.com/marriottassets/marriott/NYCXR/nycxr-bar-8322-hor-feat.jpg?downsize=1536px:* 2x" media="(min-width: 600px)"> <source srcset="https://cache.marriott.com/marriottassets/marriott/NYCXR/nycxr-bar-8322-hor-feat.jpg?interpolation=progressive-bilinear&amp;downsize=599px:*, https://cache.marriott.com/marriottassets/marriott/NYCXR/nycxr-bar-8322-hor-feat.jpg?downsize=1198px:* 2x"> <img src="https://cache.marriott.com/marriottassets/marriott/NYCXR/nycxr-bar-8322-hor-feat.jpg?downsize=1024px:*" alt="King Cole Bar" class="l-display-block" itemprop="url"> </picture>
```

How to get the url of the image which has the largest dimensions of a picture element in JavaScript

I've tried:

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll("source");

  for (m = 0; m < divs.length; m++) {
      url = img.getAttribute("data-srcset-large")||img.getAttribute("data-srcset")||img.getAttribute("srcset");
      if (url!=null) url= url.replace(/\s+[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?[wx]/g, "").split(/,/)[0];
    }
```

but it get only the first link not the largest dimensions image

Comment: Any ideas guys..

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this function to do the job..

```js
function get_filesize(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("HEAD", url, false); // Notice "HEAD" instead of "GET",
                               //  to get only the header
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == this.DONE) {
          callback(parseInt(xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Length")));
      }
  };
  xhr.send();
}



function LargestDimURLF(img){

  var Objs = [];
  var sourceElms = img.getElementsByTagName("SOURCE");

  for(k=0;k<sourceElms.length;k++){
    var sourceElm = sourceElms[k];
    var urls = sourceElm.getAttribute("srcset");

    if (urls==null) {
       for(s=0;s<sourceElm.attributes.length;s++){
        var att = sourceElm.attributes[s];
        if (att.nodeName.indexOf("data-srcset")!=-1){
          urls = att.value;
        }
       }
      
      }
    if (urls!=null) {
    
    urls= urls.replace(/\s+[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?[wx]/g, "").split(/,/);
      for(j=0;j<urls.length;j++){
        var url = urls[j];
        get_filesize(url, function(imgSize) {
          
          var Obj={"url":url,"size":imgSize}
          Objs.push(Obj);
        

        });
        


      }


    }
    
  }

      Objs.sort(function(a, b) {
          return b.size - a.size;
          
      });
      return Objs[0].url||"";
  



}

var url = LargestDimURLF(document.getElementByID("myPicture"));
```